# Choose Default Program dialog does not show up after choosing Open with entry in context menu

Tags: windows, windows-vista, file-association, file-types

For some time now when I click *Open with* from Windows Explorer's context menu I'm getting this error

> This file does not have a program
>   associated with it to perform this
>   action. Create an association in the
>   Set Associations control panel.

instead of the standard *Choose Default Program* dialog. I'm getting this error no matter what the extension of the selected file is (as long as there's *Open with* option for given extension; some extensions do not show this option). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check files associations settings

Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Set Files Associations

There you can edit associations for each file type

Comment: You missed the point. The problem is I don't get the standard `Choose Default Program` dialog for files with unknown (not associated) extensions.

Answer (score 1):

This article didn't tell me exactly how to fix it but it gave me an idea:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218805

It said to examine the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command
```

And it said to look at the following default value:

```
C:\%windir%\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL %1
```

Comment: And then what did you do?

Comment: This key didn't help me in my case.  CCleaner has removed default value from similar key:
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\opendlg\command"

I've found it by doing reverse regression testing on the reg-backup file from CCleaner (by hand).  But in general you should be OK by importing this file: https://web.archive.org/web/20150124034505/http://windowsxp.mvps.org/reg/openas_win7.reg