# Open with only lists choose default program for .py files

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, python, context-menu

The context menu for a `.py` file in file explorer is only giving the `Choose default program...` option in the context menu. Currently it runs it with python.exe by default. If I change the default program from the menu, open with still lists only choose... The choose program menu behaves normally. I only have this problem with `.py` associations as far as I know. Since I do have a default program this does not seem to be the same problem as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/750664/cannot-choose-default-program-form-open-with-context-menu-in-windows-7) or similar

How do I get the options to open with notepad, sublime, etc. to show up on the open with list?

Comment: So you're saying that once you've chosen the default program to run with a .py file as Notepad, the next time you open the file it still opens with python?

Comment: @RsyaStudios no. If I selected open with sublime by default, the next time I opened the file it would open it with sublime but there would be not change to the open with menu. I just tried notepad and for some readon it _did_ get added to the menu. The difference seems to be that in the window to choose default program, notepad was under more options and sublime was not hidden along with python.exe. Still I can't get sublime on the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is to add items to the **Open With** menu.

From another [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/690106/add-items-to-the-open-with-list-in-windows-8):

Make sure your application has `disk:\path_to\your_app.exe.ApplicationCompany` string with any meaning e.g. `Soopa-troopa soft` in `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache]`.

After creating this registry key open desired file with your application and it will appear in `Open with` list.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe.FriendlyAppName` already existed. I guess it needs to be `ApplicationCompany`. I saw that question you linked to but I thought it was a different problem. So is this a sublime install bug?