# How to associate extensionless files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-association

This used to be simple to do in XP ([example guide](http://perishablepress.com/associate-extensionless-files-with-notepad/)), but I can't figure out how to do it in Win7.

Currently extensionless files open by default in notepad (yes I have the *show file extensions* enabled).

When I try to use the **Open With** dialog to associate the **Scite** editor with such files, the *Always use the selected program* option is greyed out.

I've tried the XP trick of adding a **.** (dot) key in **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**. If I add the key **OpenWithList** to it, and then and a subkey **scite.exe**, the OpenWith context menu will show **scite**. But it still doesn't allow me to set it as the default viewer. Perhaps there's another registry trick I don't know of.

Note that simply renaming a file isn't always possible, for example I might be working on a foreign source code repository which has a posix-style extensionless *README* file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Program [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) to associate files to programs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The way this worked out was: File Types Settings > Context Menu > (then select the "." file extension, or the user should add it), (then there should be an Open command listed, or the user should add it) > Edit Selected Command > and then hit browse to your application. Then hit next, and then "Set selected command as default".

Comment: Thanks [Andrej](http://superuser.com/users/47065/andrej). This is the only way I found to make it work in Windows 8.

Comment: Just as a side-note, an already existing SU answer turned out to be easier to use: http://superuser.com/a/13947/47065

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, just gives a couple of screenshots. The response by @Andrej was the most helpful.