# How to associate extensionless files in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, file-association

I would like to associate a text reader to extentionless files in Windows 8.
On Windows 7, the steps to make that happen are described here:
[How to associate extensionless files in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/566814/how-to-associate-extensionless-files-in-windows-7)
However, I have not made these steps work on Windows 8 successfully.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could show me how to do that.

What I have tried (that didn't work) :

- I have added a `"."` key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, and associated default
  to my application, namely `sublime_text`. The value I put is
  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 2.0.1 x64\sublime_text.exe"`.
- I also tried putting `assoc .="No Extension"` `ftype "No Extension" =
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 2.0.1 x64\sublime_text.exe" "%1"`
  in an admin shell, still to no success.
- [**See edit further down] I also tried http://defaultprogramseditor.com/, which successfully changed the icon of 
  extentionless files with the icon edition part, but which had no effect on the actual
  opening of files.
- Finallly, I tried Windows 8's Default program editor. In the association menu, having 
  created a value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, I could see an entry for the `"."` format, but
  when I tried to modify the value associated to that entry, the thing that's supposed to 
  happen, namely, the popping of the association menu, did not happen. In fact, nothing
  happend.

Edit: As mentioned in my own answer, http://defaultprogramseditor.com/ ended up working. You just really need to click `"Set selected command as default"` before saving your association. Thanks to [Andrej](https://superuser.com/users/47065/andrej). [Link to his comment.](https://superuser.com/questions/566814/how-to-associate-extensionless-files-in-windows-7#comment692655_566834)

Comment: Could you describe what you've already done and/or what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Added what I tried to the question's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out [Andrej](https://superuser.com/users/47065/andrej)'s comment in the original question did the trick : [Link to Andrej's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/566814/how-to-associate-extensionless-files-in-windows-7#comment692655_566834).

With  http://defaultprogramseditor.com/, you really need to click on `"Set selected command as default"` before saving, or the association will not work.