# Default Program and Icon for Specific File Name In Windows

Tags: windows-7, file-association

Is it possible to set the default program and icon for files of a specific name? Particularly, I'm interested in setting the default program and icon for file names that typically come with open source software that don't have file extensions (e.g. `COPYING`, `README`, `INSTALL`, etc.). I know that I can set the default program for all files without an extension by adding a key named with only a period under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, but this is NOT what I want to do because I wish to use a different program (hex editor) for such files. Ideally I want to be able to use [this icon](http://www.softicons.com/toolbar-icons/gion-icons-by-silvestre-herrera/mimetypes-text-x-copying-icon) for files named `COPYING` and set the default program to Notepad++.

Again, please let me re-iterate, that I do NOT want to [set the defaults for all files without an extension](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows). I want to set the defaults for files of a **specific name**. If the file is named `COPYING` or even `COPYING.txt`, I want to to set the default program and icon for these files, but not for all files ending in `.TXT`. Just `COPYING` or `COPYING.txt`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the default program for opening files without an extension in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows)

Comment: @rrirower, this is not a duplicate. As I said in the post, I do NOT want to set the defaults for ALL files without an extension. I want to set the defaults for files of a **specific name**. Ideally, if the file is named `COPYING` or even `COPYING.TXT` I want to set that icon (but not for all `.txt` files... Only if the file is named `COPYING*`)

Comment: I dont think there is such a program out there......