# Windows make a default program for pattern of file extensions

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-extension

How to make a default program for pattern of file extensions in Windows?

Specifically, I SSH into a Linux cluster to run job scripts and there is information in a file of the form

JobName.o####

where #### is a counter of the number of jobs since the system was last reset, so it can be any length.

Doing some poking around it seems like the method described in this [question for extensionless files](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows) could be used. However, how do I handle the numbers at the end?

Comment: I typically just use `Open With` then indicate I always want the same program to be used.

Comment: Not an answer per-se but can't you either (a) have the cluster change the output format of the job names to add .something on the end or (b) just run a Linux bash script to add an extension such as: for f in JobName.*; do mv "$f" "${f%.extension}"; done   source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114004/add-file-extension-to-files-with-bash

Comment: I am reasonably sure that windows just won't do this. filetype associations exist as registry entries in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ and are the literal extension (.exe, .txt, etc). From there, the default key usually contains a path to the executable. So Windows performs the registery search using the extension on the file selected, and there is no means to perform wildcard searches of the registry.

Comment: In the end, the best bet will be to alter the job to create the files as `jobname.runcount,ext` so that you can retain the sequence, but not deal with it as a filetype extension (because it isn't a type of file.  )

Comment: Or use a batch job to rename the files on the Windows PC after download, if you can't have the extension changed on he server.