# How to set the default program for specific extensionless file?

Tags: windows, file-management, sublime-text-2

I use Docker for Windows and I work with a lot of Dockerfiles. They're an extensionless file which can be read and opened in any text editor such as Sublime or Notepad.

Related questions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows) talk about the same problem but for **every extensionless file**. I want to open **only** the Dockerfiles with Sublime, but not any other extensionless files.

Is this doable? Meaning, can I open files with specific names with a specific software application by default?

A requirement is that I can't add an extension to a Dockerfile, even if Docker can still work with it. To keep it short, this is an inflexible company standard.

Comment: Without an extension, what else is going to differentiate the file type? Even Apple mostly gave up on resource forks containing a creator code/file type & went with extensions, 20 years ago. [Their modern equivalent is to hide the extension for certain known package types, similar but not quite the same as Windows.]

Comment: Want you want is not possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin the filename is always the same: "Dockerfile", that's the only different thing between the file and every other file. But yeah I guess is not possible without extensions or something else